# Finding differences between 2 images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection

Imagine I have 2 images. Both look same but with differences. For an example, `image1` has a brochure in the image but `image2` doesn't have it, but everything else in the image2 is same as image1.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>

using namespace cv;

void readme();


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{


  Mat img_object = imread( "C:/Users/Yohan/Pictures/ironManSpecial2.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  Mat img_scene = imread("C:/Users/Yohan/Pictures/noIronMan.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

  if( !img_object.data || !img_scene.data )
  { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

  //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
  int minHessian = 400;

  SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

  detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
  detector.detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );

  //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
  SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

  Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

  extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
  extractor.compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

  //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
  FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
  std::vector< DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

  double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
  { double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
  }

  printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
  printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

  //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
  std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
  { if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
    { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
  }  

  Mat img_matches;
  drawMatches( img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene, 
               good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), 
               vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS ); 


  //-- Localize the object from img_1 in img_2 
  std::vector<Point2f> obj;
  std::vector<Point2f> scene;

  for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
  {
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt ); 
  }

  Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

  //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
  std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
  obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, 0 );
  obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, img_object.rows ); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, img_object.rows );
  std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

  perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);


  //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
  line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );

  //-- Show detected matches
  namedWindow( "Good Matches & Object detection", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
  imshow( "Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Above code is for finding "matches". This is the result of it

[image]

you can see there is an "Iron Man 3 Brochure" in the image1 (left side image) but it is not in image2 (right side image). Now, I need to find that "something" is missing in image2 and print a message in console.

What should be considered is, this "Iron Man 3 Brochure" is just an example, in real scenario I don't know what is going to missing.

How can I do this?

Comment: You may find out that images are different doing such an analysis as you've done. You can get the shape of the form using some signal processing. Now, unless you've been tracking object movement in real time and in 3 dimensions, you have no easy way to know whether something is missing, was added, or if you just got two very similar stills of the same scene. You may need to use the [Mechanical Turk method](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try align images using keypoints you find, and then find pixel wise difference, or apply template matching algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, imagine that brochure is in 2nd image as well, but it is not on that Software Engineering book. It is on that UML book. In this case, matching will fail right?

Comment: It should work, if you'll align not only book region, but entire region you want control. I think, it can be done using book keypoints.

Answer (score 2):

What information will you have about the image in advance? Will they all be similar in appearance according to certain objects present, orientation, characteristics, etc? If you have this information, you can use straight-forward point matching algorithms (ie: compute the singular value decomposition, etc).

If not, the most straightforward approach would be using a few common methods to gather some useful statistics.

First, consider histogram equalization or histogram normalization, along with some simple de-noising filters (ie: do you have Gaussian noise, and need to apply a simple smoothing filter, or impulse/salt-pepper noise and need to apply a median/mode filter?).

Now, get some basic statistics about the image. Get the average intensity value, and the variance/standard-deviation of each. If it's just a small change between the two images, these values for both images should be very similar. If not, you may need to revisit your filtering and equalization stages.

Finally, consider something like principal component analysis (ie: calculate the co-variance matrix, compute it's eigenvalues, and determine the 2 greatest values, and compute the eigenvectors associated with those values). From this, you can find the darkest or brightest features of the image, along with it's alignment, and placement (ie: centroid). You could basically have both images aligned over top of each other, and with the same orientation.

With this in place, you could crop/trim the edges of both images, and you'll have two aligned images that will look very similar. Now, the application of a threshold filter will reduce the image to black and white, and you can subtract one image from another. By virtue of the previous operations applied to the two images, the difference between the two will be only the most distinct features, and is effectively a mask that defines it graphically.

Hope this helps. If you explore this approach, I can provide more information if you find it's steering you in the right direction.

Good luck!